# Unable to navigate to other view controller after Google sign-in

Tags: swift, firebase

How can I go to another view controller after successfully signing with google? I've tried "self.inputViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMain", sender: self)" in my App Delegate but not getting any respond. Am I supposed to add the method in App Delegate or the view controller with the sign-in button?

**App Delegate**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate{

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = "my_client_id"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
    
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
          print(error)
          return
        }

        guard
          let authentication = user?.authentication,
          let idToken = authentication.idToken
        else {
          return
        }

        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
            if let error = error {
              let authError = error as NSError
                print(authError.localizedDescription)
              return
            }
            
            self.inputViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMain", sender: self)
        }

    }
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Comment: So do you get an error? Does the delegate get called? Does the seque exist in the storyboard? There is more debug information required to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure about the inputViewController is not nil? This may a reason for not working.

You can add a function to test this, or you can use the print function to check, or, you can use debug point to check inputViewController is nil or not.

I'd like to add comment but I don't have enough reputation point :).
Good luck.